# How to launch application on startup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an OSX project (objective-c) and I'd like to run it on startup.

Meaning, I want to write some code that plants my application so that it'll run upon startup. So that whenever a user will run my application for the first time it will always launch on startup for that user.

How can I do this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I disagree about this post being off topic - its a question about LSSharedFileList or similar. Read the question, don't just scan.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites." This question is definitely about programming and not off topic.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205967/12484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the launch agent.

Create an XML file like this one and place it in either ~/Library/LaunchAgents (for a single user) or /Library/LaunchAgents (for all users).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.your.program</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>--some-arg</string>
        <string>--some-other-arg</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then restart the launch agent to load your file with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.your.program.plist`

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't say this is a question for StackOverflow.
Anyway, if what you are trying to do is just to launch a cocoa application on system startup, you can do it quite simply using the "Users" pane of the system preferences.

Select your account, switch to the "login elements" pane, and add the application.

Comment: I want to write some code that plants my application so that it'll run upon startup. So that whenever a user will run my application for the first time it will always launch on startup for that user. Why is it not a question for StackOverflow?

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer. It sounded as if you wanted to run the application on startup on just your computer.

Comment: Thanks I edited the original question to be clearer. Please cancel your vote down if you don't mind.

Comment: @Nili You can add your application to login items. Have a look at [UKLOGINITEMREGISTRY](http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm#UKLoginItemRegistry).